# Having issues with discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey guys so I working on a bot but and having issues with the music part of the bot working for example the bot will join the call to play music and the commands and song type works however the bot doesn't play the music and I get this error:

(node:28364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!
at Function.getInfo (C:\Users\schne\Desktop\Test 1\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:130:11)
at Function.create (C:\Users\schne\Desktop\Test 1\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:143:38)
at new FFmpeg (C:\Users\schne\Desktop\Test 1\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:44:27)
at AudioPlayer.playUnknown (C:\Users\schne\Desktop\Test 1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js:47:20)
at VoiceConnection.play (C:\Users\schne\Desktop\Test 1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\util\PlayInterface.js:71:28)
at play (C:\Users\schne\Desktop\Test 1\commands\music\play.js:65:45)
at Object.exports.run
(C:\Users\schne\Desktop\Test 1\commands\music\play.js:41:27)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

also I have ffmpeg installed.

Comment: The error is clear. I'm pretty sure you don't have FFmpeg installed. Just to make sure, run `npm install ffmpeg-static` and `npm install @discordjs/opus`.

Comment: Please also show some relevant code.

Comment: here's the dependencies: https://pastebin.com/YjJX6PPW
as you can see FFMPEG was installed but wasn't working after I did what Jakye said it started working. Thank you